# Spring Data MongoDB Aggregation Match with Date

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, aggregation-framework

I would like to make this aggregation Pipeline in Spring data Mongo

```
    db.Events.aggregate([
                    {
                        "$match": {
                            "date": {
                                "$gte": ISODate("2017-03-13"),
                                "$lt": ISODate("2017-03-12")
                            }
                        }
                    }
])
```

So I make the match stage like this :

```
BasicDBObject("$match",
                new BasicDBObject("date",
                        new BasicDBObject("$gte","ISODate("+"2017-03-12"+")").
                                      append("$lt","ISODate("+"2017-03-13"+")")
                                 )
              );
```

But in the JS aggregation it's `"$gte": ISODate("2017-03-13")` and the result of the BasicDBObject is `"$gte": "ISODate(2017-03-13)"` So it's don't work.

Do you have any idea how can I have the same that JS result or an idea to make this match stage otherwise ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting the date value as a String:

```
new BasicDBObject("$gte","ISODate("+"2017-03-12"+")")
```

You need to create a Date object then use that in your comparison.  Something like this:

```
Date fromDate = LocalDate.parse("2017-03-12").toDate();
Date toDate = LocalDate.parse("2017-03-13").toDate();

BasicDBObject("$match",
            new BasicDBObject("date",
                    new BasicDBObject("$gte",fromDate).
                                  append("$lt",toDate)
                             )
          );
```

Comment: Thanks ! To complete your answer i would just add to use this to generate date because all of function of Java.utils.Date are deprecated : 
`Date date = LocalDate.parse("2017-03-13").toDate();`
Allow me to add that because in my search i'm don't find this
Thanks again !